# psql ERROR: could not open file "address.csv" for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, postgresql, csv

A newbie to Linux.

I am trying to copy a .csv into a PostgreSQL database,

`copy address from 'address.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;`

I have cd to location of file, using the \cd [directory] command at the psql prompt. An unsuccessful action.

I have closed that terminal window and in another terminal window cd to the data folder and from there there I have opened the psql command.

`\! pwd` displays the name/path of folder where the file is stored.
`/home/tommy/virtualenv_folder/code_data/postgresql_csv_files`

`\! ls` displays the file name, even using the wildcard `\! add*` displays the file name.

stackoverflow.com/questions/16618299/postgres-copy-from-csv-file-no-such-file-or-directory
suggests to reset the *search_path*. Being in the data folder surely this is not necessary. Or is it?

Anyway, any pointers would be appreciated, please.

Comment: Had the same issue. File and permissions were correct. However, I was using a proxy to connect to the target server. Make sure the file exists on the target server where you trying to execute this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the actual path in the copy statement, eg,

```
copy address from '/home/tommy/virtualenv_folder/code_data/postgresql_csv_files/address.csv'.
```

Also make sure that the postgres user has read access to that file and directory or change the ownership to postgres, ie, chown postgres:postgres address.csv. I tend to create a directory and give all users read/write access to it, so I can easily load data into postgres and dump it back out again, either as myself or as a postgres user, eg,

```
chmod a+rw /var/import/postgresfiles
```

The search_path relates to postgres searching through schemas within the database not in the external filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file, you want to extract data from. click on permission and in the security tab tick the read and write option.