# PostgresSQLfile permissions error using COPY

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I am using python to dump csv data into a database using Psycopg2.  I need to give Postgres permission to a specific filepath in order to use the COPY command (documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html). I need to give permission to a specific directory path route and file to avoid the following error:

```
COPY database.table_name FROM '/home/development_user/Documents/App/CSV/filename.csv' delimiter ',' csv header

ERROR:  could not open file "/home/development_user/Documents/App/CSV/filename.csv" for reading: Permission denied
```

To simplify things, want to add postgres to the development user's group.  That way, postgres should have the group read permissions the development user can easily define on a path by path basis. I added the postgres user to the development_user group using the following command and validated that it was successful:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G development_user postgres
$ groups postgres
postgres : postgres development_user
```

Here is the output of a permissions path trace using the namei -l [path] commmand

```
$ namei -l /home/development_user/Documents/App/CSV/filename.csv
drwxr-xr-x root        root        /
drwxr-xr-x root        root        home
drwxr-x--- development_user development_user development_user
drwxr-xr-x development_user development_user Documents
drwxr-xr-x development_user development_user App
drwxrwxr-x development_user development_user CSV
-rw-rw-r-- development_user development_user filename.csv
```

As you can see, anyone in the group `development_user` should now have read (`r`) and execute (`x`) permissions on all directories in the path, and also read and write permissions on the final file.  If postgres tried to access the same file as an `other` user, postgres would be limited by the `development_user` directory in ability to access.

However, when I try to access the file I get a permissions error as noted above.  When I open the `development_user` directory with `other` read and execute permissions such as the command below, I am able to read the the file is Postgres:

```
$ chmod o+rx /home/development
```

However, I do not want to grant `other` read and execute permissions for the development_user home directory, and I can't see why postgres user is not able to use the group permissions outlined above to access the same file since I added postgres to the development_user account.

Any ideas if my method to give postgres permissions to read a file by adding it to the user's group is a viable strategy?  I do not want to use another solution such as mentioned here: ([PostgreSQL - inconsistent COPY permissions errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263408/postgresql-inconsistent-copy-permissions-errors)) or here ([Postgres ERROR: could not open file for reading: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463074/postgres-error-could-not-open-file-for-reading-permission-denied/19466558)) which advise opening up permissions by setting the file owner to be postgres:postgres.  or opening up the directory permissions to widely such as allowing all users to read and execute on the development home directory. I also do not want to create another directory in the system directories and be forced to save files there as suggested here: ([psql ERROR: could not open file "address.csv" for reading: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310478/psql-error-could-not-open-file-address-csv-for-reading-no-such-file-or-direc)).

Comment: Is the PostgreSQL user that is trying to run the copy command a superuser? If you `sudo -i -u postgres` can you access the file you're getting a permission error for?

Comment: The development_user account is a sudoer.  I could run the python script as a sudo command, however I'm most curious to get this solution to work since I could use it from a non sudoer.  I'm also looking at using psychopg2 copy_expert function to open the file and feed it in using STDIN, so, the permissions can stay strict.

Comment: I mean that the PostgreSQL user that is running the Copy command needs the be a database superuser in order to access files.  This is the user that is in the psycopg2 connection string.  The `sudo -i -u postgres` bit was to verify that the postgres user, which is by default the system user that PostgreSQL is running as, can access the files.

Comment: I understand.  The answer is no.  I have created another Postgres user and granted 'all' permissions to the specific database in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved this problem particular to use psychopg2 cursor class function copy_expert (Docs: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html). copy_expert allows you to use STDIN therefore bypassing the need to issue a superuser privilege for the postgres user.

From Postgres COPY Docs (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> Do not confuse COPY with the psql instruction \copy. \copy invokes
>   COPY FROM STDIN or COPY TO STDOUT, and then fetches/stores the data in
>   a file accessible to the psql client. Thus, file accessibility and
>   access rights depend on the client rather than the server when \copy
>   is used.

You can also leave the permissions set strictly for access to the development_user home folder and the App folder.

```
            sql = "COPY table_name FROM STDIN DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER"
            self._cursor.copy_expert(sql, open(csv_file_name, "r"))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [PostgreSQL Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> COPY naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers,
>   since it allows reading or writing any file that the server has
>   privileges to access.

So the PostgreSQL user doing the copying must be a database superuser.

You can do this with the `ALTER ROLE` command:

```
ALTER ROLE <rolename> WITH SUPERUSER
```

Also:

> COPY with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read
>   from or write to a file. The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL
>   user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified
>   from the viewpoint of the server.
>
> ...
>
> Files named in a COPY command are read or written directly by the
>   server, not by the client application. Therefore, they must reside on
>   or be accessible to the database server machine, not the client.

The default system user that PostgreSQL runs on is `postgres`.  Ensure that that user has access to the files you want to copy.  You can test this by using the command `sudo -i -u postgres` to become the postgres user and then trying to view the files.

Comment: I managed to avoid giving superuser privileges by using the psychopg2 cursor class function copy_expert.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on @jonnyjandles answer, since that shows a mystery `self._cursor` -- a more typical invocation might be like:

```
copy_command = f"COPY table_name FROM STDIN CSV HEADER;"
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.copy_expert(copy_command, open(some_file_path, "r"))
```